# Identity Server 4 - Autenticate with refreshed token

Tags: identityserver4

I'm approaching with identity Server 4 recenly and after read the documentation and try the examples project i have some difficulty in thi scenario:

1 - Logged-in with a provider (ex. Google)
2 - I ask to my IS4 a token passing the code_token of Google
3 - i obtain a new valid token from my IS4
4 - Store the new token and use it for autenticate from now

My problem is in the point 4 because i don't know how store into MVC application the new token

```
HttpContext.GetTokenAsync("access_token")
```

This call i every time null.

```
  AuthenticationProperties authProp = new AuthenticationProperties();
            authProp.StoreTokens(new List<AuthenticationToken>
                {
                    new AuthenticationToken { Name = OpenIdConnectParameterNames.IdToken, Value = newIdToken },
                    new AuthenticationToken { Name = OpenIdConnectParameterNames.AccessToken, Value = newAccessToken },
                    new AuthenticationToken { Name = OpenIdConnectParameterNames.RefreshToken, Value = newRefreshToken },
                    new AuthenticationToken { Name = OpenIdConnectParameterNames.AcrValues, Value = string.Format("idp:{0} email:{1}", model.Provider, model.Email) }
                });

            SignIn(new ClaimsPrincipal(identity), authProp, "oidc");
```

After do that saving the new tokens and adding the provider into the AcrValues
If i go in a page with **[Authorize]** the call made to the IS4 is without AcrValues and return no logged user.

What I missed on the way?

Thanks

Comment: Did you set the authentication scheme 'oidc' in the IdentityServerOptions? Also, I'd recommend using the IdentityServer extension methods for signing in by calling 'HttpContext.SignInAsync' instead. They'll relieve a lot of headache and will ensure your ClaimsPrincipal is made uniformly: https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/blob/63a50d7838af25896fbf836ea4e4f37b5e179cd8/src/Extensions/HttpContextAuthenticationExtensions.cs

Comment: I think i might have misunderstood you in my post above. Are you trying to store tokens from Google using IdentityServer's MVC controller or are you making an ordinary standalone client to your identityServer?

Comment: @Randy i have make a client to my identityServer and i try to make 'HttpContext.SignInAsync'  with a new token.
But i can't figure it out.
Could you post a code ex ample for call the SigninAsync with a token ?